# Importing Thawte trial certificates into a Java keystore

Tags: tomcat, ssl, pki, thawte

I'm trying to configure a Tomcat server with SSL. I've generated a keypair thus:

```
$ keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore keys
```

Next I generate a certificate signing request:

```
$ keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore keys -file tomcat.csr
```

Then I copy-paste the contents of `tomcat.csr` into a form on Thawte's website, asking for a trial SSL certificate. In return I get two certificates delimited with `-----BEGIN ... -----END`, that I save under `tomcat.crt` and `thawte.crt`. (Thawte calls the second certificate a 'Thawte Test CA Root' certificate).

When I try to import either of them it fails:

```
$ keytool -importcert -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt -keystore keys
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply

$ keytool -importcert -alias thawte -file thawtetest.crt -keystore keys
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Adding the `-trustcacerts` option to either of these commands doesn't change anything either.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally understood what was going on here. It turns out that the replies that I got from Thawte are formatted as PKCS#7, whereas `keytool` expects certificated in the X.509 format.

`openssl` can be used to convert certificates from one format to another:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in thawtetest.crt -print_certs |
  openssl x509 > thawtetest.x509
```

Now you can import `thawtetest.x509` with keytool, and `tomcat.crt` right behind it.

Comment: Thanks... You would think they would mention this in the e-mail... Since the intermediate one (also in the e-mail) is x509!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import PKCS#7 chains using keytool, so long as you're using a more recent version.  Exporting the certs into distinct files will work, too, but if you're running a recent version of keytool there should be no problem importing the PKCS#7 file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Having run into the same trouble I found [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/420253/Security/Failed-establish-chain) which helped me out.  I put the trial certificates I received into a single file and used keytool to import making **sure the ALIAS (keytool -alias param) I used was different** (ie not the same alias I used when creating the certificates for the request).  It is a bizarre error message given it simply doesn't like you trying to import to the same alias.